# D3 - Select element in this svg?

Tags: d3.js

I have a codepen here - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yvgJKB

I have two d3 charts with different data.

I want to have tooltips on the bars so when you rollover them it shows the value.

I want the tooltip to be separate html in the svg cos the actual charts are responsive and I dont want the tooltips to scale with the svg.

The tooltip works as expected in the top chart.

In the bottom chart the tooltip appears in the top chart.

I think this is becasue the `let tooltip = d3.select('.tooltip').append("div")` is selecting the first tooltip which is in the first chart.

The charts and tooltip is dynamically created.

This there a way in the D3 to say `d3.select('.tooltip')` in this svg something like `d3.select(this)('.tooltip')`

```
let tooltip = d3.select('.tooltip').append("div")
    .attr("class", "tip")
    .style("display", "none")
    .attr("fill", "grey");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of unnecessary repetition in your code.

Create the tooltip div only **once**. Also, since you are *creating* the div in your D3 code, you don't need any div with the `tooltip` class in your HTML. Remove both.

Besides that, use `d3.event.pageX` and `d3.event.pageY` to position your tooltip div anywhere in the page. A single tooltip div can be used to show the tooltip to any number of SVGs you have on that page.

Here is your updated CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KQaBvE?editors=0010

Answer (score 1):

Tooltips should be created separately by selecting different charts (or some other unique marker) and given unique variable names within the same scope:

```
let tooltip1 = d3.select('.chart1').append("div")
    .attr("class", "tip")
    .style("display", "none")
    .attr("fill", "grey");
```

---

```
let tooltip2 = d3.select('.chart2').append("div")
    .attr("class", "tip")
    .style("display", "none")
    .attr("fill", "grey");
```

https://codepen.io/mortonanalytics/pen/BYpwaz